# React won't load images

Tags: reactjs, image, load

I am building a react blog and my images won't load. It shows me this message in console - src\components\BlogPost\index.js

```
  Line 21:11:  Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce `img` tags as an image. You don’t need to use the words `image`, `photo,` or `picture` (or any specified custom words) in the alt prop  jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt.
```

My source:

```
const BlogPost = (props) => { 
  return( 
  <div className="blogPostContainer"> 
    <Card> 
      <div className="blogHeader"> 
        <span className="blogCategory">Featured</span> 
          <h1 className="postTitle">..</h1> 
        <span className="postedBy">..</span> 
      </div> 
     <div className="postimageContainer"> 
        <img src={require('../../blogPostimages/memories-from.jpg')} alt="Post image" /> 
     </div> 
    </Card> 
   </div> )
 }
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Show some source code -- otherwise, there's no way to diagnose for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="example" aria-hidden alt="Picture of me taking a photo of an image" />
```

add "aria-hidden "

Answer (score 0):

1. *Redundant alt attribute* warning doesn't prevent image loading. It means there is a meaningless alt in your image. alt attribute is useful for accessibility and must describe the image if the download fails.

Use an accurate description for images or `alt=""` for backgrounds and decorations.

2. Loading errors probably are caused by imports errors. Check image path, name, and location.
   Here an example of an image import.

```
import logo from '../static/logo.png';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <img src={logo} alt='website logo' />
  )
}
```